# Can I display an SRT video stream in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, avkit

I have a camera that produces an srt stream; I'd like to be able to embed that stream live in a SwiftUI app. I was hoping that this would work:

```
import AVKit
...
VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "srt://192.168.68.101:9000")!)).frame(width: 320, height: 180)
```

but that gives me a blank video screen with a non-functional play button.

The same URL (srt://192.168.68.101:9000) opens just fine in VLC.

Any hints?